# typescript - while loop for promise

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, promise

I've a large array which is split into smaller chunks. Then I make an asyncronous call on each chunk:

```
  myFunc(arrObjs: any[], chunkSize: number): Promise<any> {
    let result = Promise.resolve(); // To start the chain

    while(arrObjs.length) {
      // Extracting array chunk
      let chunk = arrObjs.splice(0, chunkSize);
      // Building the chain
      result = result.then(() => {
        return someAsynFunc(
          chunk
        );
      });
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Above my solution. I need to run async functions in order (series promise), so I build a chain of promises.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: if you are going to wait for the previous async chunk processing to finish before starting the next one what's the purpose of doing all of this async in the first place?

Comment: I've no control over the async function, it's inherently async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `reduce` pattern:

```
function myFunc(arrObjs: any[], chunkSize: number): Promise<any> {
    const chunks : any[] = [];
    while (arrObjs.length) {
        chunks.push(arrObjs.splice(0, chunkSize));
    }

    return chunks.reduce((p : Promise<any>, chunk : any[]) => {
        return p.then(() => someAsyncFunc(chunk));
    }, Promise.resolve());
  }
```

*(I think I have those type annotations right; if not, hopefully you can read past it...)*

Note that I've preserved your original behavior actually removing the data from the `arrObjs` array, but normally I wouldn't advocate changing the object passed from the caller like that.

Here's an example:

```js
function myFunc(arrObjs, chunkSize) {
  const chunks = [];
  while (arrObjs.length) {
    chunks.push(arrObjs.splice(0, chunkSize));
  }

  return chunks.reduce((p, chunk) => {
    return p.then(() => someAsyncFunc(chunk));
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

function someAsyncFunc(chunk) {
  console.log("Start handling", JSON.stringify(chunk));
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Done handling", JSON.stringify(chunk));
      resolve();
    }, 800);
  });
}

const array = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
myFunc(array, 3).then(() => {
  console.log("Done");
});
```

---

Also note that the above removes all chunks from the array *in advance* of processing them. If you want to do it *as* they're processed (which creates cross-talk with anything else using that array, which could add/remove/etc.), you can do much the same thing, just without `reduce`:

```
// Cross-talky version
function myFunc(arrObjs : any[], chunkSize : number) : Promise<any> {
  return new Promise<any>(function processChunk(resolve : function) {
    const chunk : any[] = arrObjs.splice(0, chunkSize);
    if (chunk.length == 0) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      someAsyncFunc(chunk).then(() => processChunk(resolve));
    }
  });
}
```

```js
// Cross-talky version
function myFunc(arrObjs, chunkSize) {
  return new Promise(function processChunk(resolve) {
    const chunk = arrObjs.splice(0, chunkSize);
    if (chunk.length == 0) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      someAsyncFunc(chunk).then(() => processChunk(resolve));
    }
  });
}

function someAsyncFunc(chunk) {
  console.log("Start handling", JSON.stringify(chunk));
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Done handling", JSON.stringify(chunk));
      resolve();
    }, 800);
  });
}

const array = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
myFunc(array, 3).then(() => {
  console.log("Done");
});
setTimeout(() => {
  array.splice(2, 0, 'cross', 'talk');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What about the memory usage of your solution? It keeps in memory the chunked array till the complete chain has been resolved.

Comment: @user51713: Normally that's not an issue (you didn't flag up that this was a memory-sensitive situation in your question). If it is an issue, you'll want to do something else (like the cross-talky version I added later).